# Passing Variables From One Class To Another

Tags: java, class, object, methods, this

In this particular scenario, I created a Packet pk which is basically an object that consists of 3 BigIntegers. In my particular `Sender` class, after generating this packet, I am attempting to pass it to my `Network` class.

In my network class. I am attempting to assign the two variable packets I declared, (inFromSender, outToReciever). Specifically, I want to assign the value of pk, or the packet that I created in the `Sender` class, to the `inFromSender` packet created in the `Network` class through the use of a method.

Is this possible?

I attempted to assign it through the s`endPacketToNetwork()` method already, however, it gives me a "*No enclosing instance of the type Network is accessible in scope*" error.

Here is my code.

```
Sender Class:

    private Packet pk;
    public Sender() {
        System.out.println("----Sender is created-----");

        //First value is message, second value is signature, third value is session key. 

        // Message = string to BigInt
        //signature = 
        pk = new Packet(new BigInteger("13"), new BigInteger("2"),new BigInteger("5"));
        System.out.println("The test packet to be sent to network is :\n " + pk.toString());
    }

    public void generateMessage()
    {

    }

    public void sendPacketToNetwork()
    {
        Network.this.inFromSender = pk;
    }
    public Packet getPacket(){
           return pk;
    }
}
```

And here is my Network class:

```
public class Network {
    Packet inFromSender, outToReceiver;
    Network() {
        System.out.println("----Network is created-----");
        inFromSender = new Packet(); 
        outToReceiver =  new Packet();
    }

    public Packet receiveFromSender() {
        return outToReceiver;
    }
}
```

If this isn't possible, is there a simpler way to achieve the same thing? Particularly through a method in the Sender class?

EDIT:
I've created a tester just to test passing the packet to the network.

```
public class tester 
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Test 1: Given Code.......................");
        //Test 1: Given Code
        Sender Sender1 = new Sender();
        Receiver Reciever1 = new Receiver();
        Network Network1 = new Network();

        Sender1.sendPacketToNetwork();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show how this code is being used/called.

Comment: @ScaryWombat I included my tester.

Comment: You have to create methods that take parameters e.g. `Sender1.sendPacketToNetwork(Reciever1);`

Comment: Also please stick to java naming standards

Comment: The packet is being send first to the network, then the receiver. The receiver is not a part of this particular issue.

Comment: What on earth is `Network.this.inFromSender = pk;` ?  If you want `Sender` to know about `Network` then you should send the value of the `Network` object to the `Sender` object via a parameter

Comment: @ScaryWombat is right. Your implementation needs to have some mechanism to relate the classes. You have 3 separate classes which don't have any methods to connect each other. When you initialize Sender(), you should pass values in for creating the packet. When you create a Network() object, you might consider passing in a reference to sender and receiver. What you have is too far from workable code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what you are trying to accomplish, this should work but this is not a good design and you should read more about how to do whatever it is you are trying to do.

Change your Sender class's method to:

```
public void sendPacketToNetwork(Network n)
{
    n.inFromSender = pk;
}
```

Change your test code to:

```
public class Tester 
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Test 1: Given Code.......................");
        //Test 1: Given Code
        Sender sender1 = new Sender();
        Receiver reciever1 = new Receiver();
        Network network1 = new Network();

        Sender1.sendPacketToNetwork(network1);
    }
}
```

What you are doing here is passing the reference for Network to Sender class. After that, you can do what you need to do with the network object.

PS: I have changed some variable names to better follow java naming standards.

Comment: Thank you! I'm rather new to java so I didn't even know this was an option!